# Same width with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following part. I already tried to do it, but so far without any success.

```css
.container {
    width: 600px;
}

.row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 60px;
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

.item > .selector {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.item > .label-text {
    background-color: silver;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 1</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Small Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 2</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">longer Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 3</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Soo long Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 4</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sadly I'm not able to modify the structure. There are sooo much JS using the structure. But I can edit the CSS. I'm absolutely not experienced with flex box.

The text in the `span.label-text` elements can be any long but can't be longer than the half of it's parent width.

Its a plugin and its used in many parts. I can't just define a fix width.

Is it possible to make all `span.label-text` elements as wide as the one with the longest text without modifying the html or using JS for it?

Comment: You need apply width in ".item > .label-text" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using *Flexbox*, you can play around with the `flex` *values* of both *flex-items* of the `.item` element, e.g.:

```css
.container {
    width: 600px;
}

.row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 60px;
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

.item > .selector {
    display: flex;
    flex: 2; /* added; makes it twice as wide as the .label-text */
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.item > .label-text {
    background-color: silver;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1; /* added */
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; /* added */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 1</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Small Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 2</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">longer Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 3</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Soo long Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 4</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, it looks I forgot it from the description. I can't just add a fix width because its a plugin in a bigger system. And text can be any long.

And what the customer wants is to, the make all of the labels as wide as the one with the longer text.

Comment: Not possible pure CSS way because not all elements are related, would need JS/jQuery for this.

Answer (score 4):

Here is jQuery example with check **label-text** max width in all items and apply width to all **label-text**.

```js
var width =0
  jQuery('.item').each(function() {
   
   if(width <= jQuery(this).children(".label-text").outerWidth())
   {
    width = jQuery(this).children(".label-text").outerWidth();
   }
  });
  jQuery(".label-text").css('width',Math.ceil(width));
```

```css
body { margin:0; padding:0;}
  
  .container {
   width: 600px;
  }
  
  .row {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .item {
   width: 100%;
   border: 1px solid silver;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   min-height: 60px;
   flex: 1 1 0;
  }
  
  .item > .selector {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   padding-left: 20px;
  }
  
  .item > .label-text {
   background-color: silver;
   color: white;
   padding: 0 10px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 1</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Small Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 2</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">longer Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 3</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Soo long Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 4</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a width for that label-text.

```css
.container {
    width: 600px;
}

.label-text {
   width: 150px;
}

.row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 60px;
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

.item > .selector {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.item > .label-text {
    background-color: silver;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 1</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Small Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 2</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">longer Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 3</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Soo long Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <label class="item">
                <div class="selector">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <span>Option 4</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label-text">Text</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```